# Доказать неполную синонимичность

Tags: значение-слов, словообразование, недопустимая-метка, фразеология

Пишу работу по социологии. По ряду параметров работа синергетическая. В части лингвистики прочитала массу материала по следующим вопросам: система терминов, мотивационные ситуации, синонимичность, синонимические выражения, омонимия и др. На мой вопрос полученные познания не ответили. Суть вопроса: в какой связи (с точки зр.лингвистики) находятся между собой словосочетания: 
Основное рассматриваемое словосочетание Словосочетания –«оппоненты»
    Общественный договор
ПРАВО НА ИНФОРМАЦИЮ Совместные декларации
    Право дать согласие
    Регулирование прав и свобод
    Собственное согласие
    Трактовка взаимоотношений
    Согласие, данное через народных представителей
    Представительство народа в законодательном собрании
    Право организовывать мирные сходки
    Собрание для обсуждения
    трактат
    Письменное или устное обращение
    Право добиваться и обретать счастье
    Общие интересы
    Избирательное право
    Создание и формирование законов, актов, ортодоксов
    выборы
    Написание статей, издание сборников
    Договор
    Коллективное управление
    Идея равенства
    свободы
    Избирательные права
    Совещательный орган
    Совет колонии
    ассамблея
    самоуправление
    И др.
Цель: как доказать, что эти словосочетания синонимичны или неполностью синонимичны или требуется иное лингвистическое определение, чтобы доказать, что они тесно связаны между собой, близки по смыслу или являются следствием друг друга или находятся в тесной связи др. с другом? Как научно «узаконить» смысловое родство этих словосочетаний?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вообще не вижу синонимии этих словосочетаний.

Я бы назвала это терминами одной тематической группы.. (ИЛИ словосочетаниями одной тематической группы)

Семантические соответствия и ассоциации часто являются признаком параллельной связи предложений в тексте, хотя бывает, что и последовательной, а вот синонимы(лексические и контекстные, говорят о цепной, т.е. последовательной связи)

Может, это Вам поможет...

Comment: Действительно, синонимии здесь нет. Общность заключается в том, что все словосочетания являются,  как отметила Людмила, ''терминами одной тематической группы''. Можно еще выделить один стиль - Официально-деловой.